# Software for avatar/user picture creation

Tags: windows, software-rec, user-profiles

I am looking for a software that allow me creating different user pictures/avatars. 
For example, like the one of my picture profile.

I know that do exist many different online services, but I need to do it offline, for many users.

Do you know if does exists a software of this type?

Comment: Interactive or automatic?

Comment: On what basis do you wish to create it ?

Comment: @Nifle interactive is ok

Comment: @Sathya I would like to create them to respect their real face but cartoonish (look at my avatar for example)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Photo to Cartoon](http://www.caricaturesoft.com/products/photo-to-cartoon/download.html) , [AutoVector](http://www.caricaturesoft.com/products/auto-vector.html) or [Photos](http://www.caricaturesoft.com/products/photos.html).